# NodeJS res.body is undefined only on one router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I am sending data using swift to a nodeJS server.
Here is the Swift Code:

```
var data:[String:String] = [:]
data["ABC"] = "nothing"
let req = HTTPRequest(url_to_request: "https://xxx.xxx.xx.x/update", method: HTTPRequest.HTTPRequestMethod.post, data: Profile.toJSON(dict: data))
```

Here is the NodeJS:

```
console.log("Server is up!");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
  assert = require('assert');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var sslOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem', 'utf8'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem', 'utf8'),
  passphrase: 'phrase',
  rejectUnauthorized: false
};


var app = express();


//Variables:

var httpPort = 8888;
var httpsPort = 8443;



app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false,
  limit: '20mb'
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json({
  limit: '50mb'
}));

// parse application/json json size limit

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded




// setup server
app.set("port_https", httpsPort);

//check secure connection

app.all("*", function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("Secure connection: " + req.secure);
  if (req.secure) {
    return next();
  }
  res.redirect("https://" + req.hostname + ":" + app.get("port_https") + req.url);
});








// add User

app.post('/register', register);
//signIn
app.post('/login', logIn);

//Update user's profile details.

app.post('/update', updateProfile);

// Request profile details.
app.post('/profile', profileRequest);


function updateProfile(req, res) {
  console.log(res.body); // ---> undefined
}
```

When I send a post request with data to login, profile, register routers res.body is working well. But when I send data to update for some reason req.body is undefined:

ERROR:

```
Server: Secure connection: true

Server: undefined #----> log of res.body

Server: Connected successfully to databse!

stderr: /home/asaf/NodeJS/IBQA/IBQA_Server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:350
          throw err
          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'ABC' of undefined
    at /*****/server.js:92:33
    at connectCallback (*****/mongo_client.js:428:5)
    at /*****/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:347:11
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:419:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)

closing code: 1
```

Comment: does `updateProfile` has `function(req, res){...}` structure?

Comment: Yes, I will add it right now.

Comment: Could it be a possible bag?

Comment: I don't know how it works with swift, but when doing `post` you have to specify `name` attributes of `input` element inside of `form` element

Comment: I am sending it as "application/json"

Comment: there is no property `"ABC"` on data since it is undefined, check the properties of data and also `req.body` not `res`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request if there in the `req` variable, `res` is used to send the response. Try `console.log(req.body)`

Comment: Silly mistakes are the bane of programming xD. Accept the answer if you please :)

Comment: Can you please upvote the post so I will be able to submit more posts...